# word choice good / suitable

Tags: word-choice

> A piece of fruit and a cup of coffee are ( good / suitable )for me.

I think both are possible but I'm not sure.

Are both of them possible?

Comment: What is it you're trying to express?

Comment: in this context, I'll *not* go for suitable as it has nothing to do with my 'look! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct - both are possible. The only difference is in how formal or colloquial you want to sound.

If I were at a friend's house, or at a job interview, or ordering food, or really in any social situation, I would certainly go with "good" over "suitable."

"Suitable" sounds very stuffy and overly-complicated to me. I don't think it is a word I would even use at a job interview. It also isn't quite as positive as "good" - while both words will convey the idea that fruit and coffee work for you, "good" has positive emotions attached to it, while "suitable" just means that it suits you. These sorts of connotations vary from person to person, but I think it's safe to say that "suitable" is a more robotic and less frequently used word than "good" for this purpose.

---

An even more colloquial way of saying this that you'll hear very often in the United States is, "An apple and a cup of coffee **works** for me." I, personally, and probably many other Americans, would prefer that over "good" and "suitable."

Another option here, depending on context, would be "Coffee **sounds good** to me." This would be a great response to somebody asking you out to get coffee, or if you were at a coffee shop and somebody suggested getting coffee.